# Robotframework: how to use the jsonp in robotframework script

Tags: robotframework

Now I need to write a script about something like these:

```
${result}    set variable    {}
create session    url    http://xxx
${resp}    get request    url    /
should be equal as strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
Dictionary Should Contain Value    ${resp.jsonp(${result})}    Success
log    ${resp.jsonp(${result})}
```

But the URL write with jSonp script.
then how the  robotframework use with jSonp and the jSon script?
and it error like this:

```
Invalid variable name `${resp.jsonp({})}`.
```

all is these:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MkON.png)

The jsonp comes from the url.And the url writes with jsonp script. and i need to use the RobotFramework get the url interface script.may be my script is wrong.

Comment: Please take time to ensure your question is well thought out and formatted correctly.  I re-read this several times and was relatively clueless.  From what you've typed, are you using the Requests Library?  If you're playing with JSON I'd recommend using the http library

Comment: yes.all the using are:*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           HttpLibrary
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           Collections

Comment: if playing with json ,the github has a test like this:https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests.   but i don't know the script with JSONP.   and our programmer use the JSONP script wirte the interface.

Comment: what happens if you use .content like I mentioned in my answer below?  I'm afraid I'm not familiar with trying to use JSONP but I would expect you can find what you need from my suggestion.  The problem is you've just made up ${resp.jsonp}  this doesn't exist and you don't create it.

Comment: thanks anyway.may be i need to change the way to get the interface .

Comment: have you tried the answer I've given below?  Feedback on that might help us get closer

Answer (score 0):

Where has jsonp come from?  I think you want to be using ${resp.content} as you've sent a GET request from the Requests Library

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the Robotframework-Requests library, based on the code you provided.

The response object that is returned has no `.jsonp()` method. It does have a `.json()` method, which takes no arguments and returns a dictionary:

```
Dictionary Should Contain Value    ${resp.json()}    Success
```

You can also save this to a variable if you are going to perform multiple checks:

```
${json}=    set variable    ${resp.json()}
Dictionary Should Contain Value    ${json}    Success
```